# Changing the path of a batch file (.bat)

Tags: windows, batch-file

How can we change the path of a batch file (.bat) ?

Comment: which path you are talking about ?

Comment: Am talking about modifying the main path of a MS-DOS batch file

Comment: Are you talking about the `%PATH%` environment variable? ie. the directories that get searched for an executable when a command is issued?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've got a feeling it is about changing the current working directory.

To do that, use the command `cd` to change current working directory.

```
@echo off
C:
cd C:\Windows\System32\
```

If you change both the current drive *and* the current directory you'll need the `/D` switch:

```
cd /D D:\Foo
```

Comment: I think the 2nd line (c:\\) shouldnt have \ at the end if you are trying to switch drives.

Answer (score 2):

as in adding a temporary extra path to %PATH%?

try:
set path=%PATH%;c:\folder

where c:\folder is what you want to add

if you want a permanent path set use a tool called "setx"

otherwise you could call something directly without using CD etc using something like "c:\folder\program.exe"

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, make sure you change the drivename to.
then use cd command

```
c:
cd "c:\windows\"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
cd /d d:\foo
```

or, if you want to jump back to the source directory

```
pushd d:\foo
```

with

```
popd
```

you switch back to the directory before the pushd

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about changing the path of a command within the batch file?  If yes then pass the path as an argument.

Hope I understood your question.